# Where to ask a question about "development workflow"?

Tags: discussion, iphone, ios

I'd like to know where can I post question to get opinion on development workflow for iOS.

I posted a question (see below) on stack overflow and got closed because it was not related to code. I was advised to post it here. I did and my question got closed again and I was advised to post it to stack overflow.. I even tried reddit ios forum and my question got closed because it's technical.. I really feel helpless. Can you folks suggest a place where this question is considered proper?

> I'm a PM new to iOS development (running my own small startup). I'm
> trying to figure out what the best development workflow is for us.
>
> In web development, my team runs on 2-week sprint. We would
> consistently push new features to staging, and we deploy once a week
> on Friday.
>
> For iOS, I guess TestFlight internal release is the "staging". Since
> each build takes quite a lot of time (unlike web), should engineers
> consistently push new features to staging during the sprint? When and
> how does PM check off features to be released to production?
>
> In general, i'm curious to know - how does your team manage staging
> and production? how often do you push to staging and deploy?
>
> Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think stack exchange has a startup advice and service offering site, but the directory is here and each site has very detailed guidance about their intended scope and where things commonly are off scope.

- https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday

Other than sprinkling iOS and Testfligt in the question, it really wouldn’t be different if you were a startup for Android, windows, or any game console.

You may struggle on stack exchange to ask advice and guidance and synthesis questions. What is the best “workflow” isn’t much different than the best “display” or the best “editor”.

This is covered very generally in the “what not to ask” section of help - https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

It’s also something covered in many blog and meta posts, starting with this one explaining that real questions have answers and what’s reasonable scope. Managing a team depends so much on your skills, your budget that any answer tends to fall apart without very specific inputs. At some point you just have to do the work to manage your team and process.

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/
- https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/

Look at the reasons why gorilla vs shark discourages some classes of questions. Those ideas apply to your question I think and would result in lots of down votes if you ask this on stack exchange focused on using products as opposed to developing apps.

- difficult to learn from a “how to workflow” question similar to yours
- Lacks details. Is small 5 people or 50?

As to here, it’s super clear your question is more for peer collaboration and software coaching - you need mentors and feedback loops, not a book or someone random on the internet giving you a snap judgment on what they assume you are trying to learn or do.

Comment: My question wasn't what's the BEST. I just want to hear different opinions from teams and compare them myself.

Comment: Bingo! It starts with let’s discuss options, everyone share a take, then it moves to what’s the best take. You are understanding the process perfectly @user3810193. This isn’t a discussion forum. Did you look over the [tour] and read it carefully?

Answer (score 0):

This question would get marked as off-topic on the main Ask Different site. Kindly consider reading [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

You can consider posting your question on:

- [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), and/or
- [Project Management Stack Exchange](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Also, consider reading the help articles on the respective websites, ([here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), to better ensure that you keep them on-topic.

Comment: thanks i will try se stack exchange

Comment: However it will be off topic there. You are asking for opinions which is off-topic on almost all StackExchnage sites.

Comment: @mmmmmm is correct. It’s better to describe your research to define your workflow problem and how your research doesn’t solve it. That will be in topic in many places I expect.